# Gremlin - How to filter edges on property when getting shortest path

Tags: gremlin, janusgraph, gremlin-server, gremlinpython

The following query searches for the set of shortest paths from a given vertex (377524408) to another vertex that has an edge with the property `test_property`, and exits after 3 iterations (i.e. if no vertex is found on 3 traverses, we return no paths).

```
s.V(377524408).repeat(both().simplePath())
    .until(or(__.bothE().has('test_feature', gt(0)), 
              loops().is(lt(4))))
    .path().dedup().toList()
```

However, **I want to filter the edges on which the above query traverses.**

For example, only traverse edges that have a property `filter_property` < 100. How would I modify the above query to include this edge filter?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Instead of `both().simplePath()` you would use `bothE().has('filter_property', lt(100)).otherV()`.

Also, note, that `loops().is(lt(4))` will always evaluate `true` in the first iteration. You probably want that to be `loops().is(3)`.